Ethernet is not working on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm a new Ubuntu user and I don't know what happened. Here are the current settings.
Results of sudo lshw -C network:

Results of nmcli-device:

Results of ifconfig:

Results of sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:


Have a look in the help centre - https://askubuntu.com/help for details on how to ask here - and please don’t supply text as pictures - it’s impossible for people to work with those.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
